# NotifyPropertyChanged of datagrid readonly column

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a list of object bin to a datagrid
this object have a property readonly (only a get) which is build from the other properties
like proA = "toto", propB = "tata", propC => "this " + propA + " is a beautiful " + propB
My viewmodel call OnPropertyChange on the list but the value propC is not update.

```
//model
public class MyClass
{
    public string PropA { get; set; }
    public string PropB { get; set; }
    public string PropC
    {
        get
        {
            return "this is " + PropA + " and " + PropB;
        }
    }
}
//Viewmodel
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<MyClass> _myClassesList;
    public List<MyClass> MyClassesList
    {
        get
        {
            return _myClassesList;
        }
        set
        {
            _myClassesList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyClassesList");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}

//View
<Window x:Class="test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="test" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid          
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyClassesList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn                         
                        Binding="{Binding Path=PropA, Mode=TwoWay}">                
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn                         
                        Binding="{Binding Path=PropB, Mode=TwoWay}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn                         
                        Binding="{Binding Path=PropC, Mode=OneWay}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How can i make the value of PropC in view update while i update ProA or ProB ?

I try to implémente INotifyPropertyChanged in my model to solve the problème but i see in a lot of website saying that the model shouldn't implement it.

What can i do to force the readonly column to update while other update ?

Comment: Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in MyClass and fire the PropertyChanged event for PropC in the setters of PropA and PropB.

Comment: so the best way is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in Model and not in ViewModel ?

Comment: Sure, why would you not do that? How else should a MyClass instance notify about changes of its properties? The separation into model and view model is questionable anyway here. You could as well say that MyClass is part of your view model.

Comment: it's a simplification of a bigger code i can't show. so i place the INotifyPropertyChange on Model. thx for your answer